# Add a new row to table MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB we have the following scenario:

```
A a Table size 9*14088
```

The first column of table are the 'RowNames' and the rest of columns are numeric and string values.

```
A(:,1:2)
```

result:

```
Info     m1
¯¯¯¯    ¯¯¯¯  
 F1     11.55
 F2     5e+6
 F3     1.5e+7
 F4     0.0011
 F5     0.0062
 F6     '00000089.mp4'
 F7     3255 
 F8     130.6
```

Given a NUMERIC array of size 1*14087, I want to add it as new entry IN the last row in my Table and give my table the RowName 'F9' ;

I have tried 'array2table()' and 'table()' but none were successful. How can I do this?

Comment: a simple search on google results: "Add and Delete Table Rows" -> http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-rows.html you need to convert your numeric array to cell array, add your RowName and modify its property using T2.Properties.VariableNames. Then you can concatenate it to your table. And there is also a `addRow` which you can check out.

Comment: Why not `A{end+1,:} = {'F9', zeros(1,14087)}` . Your usage of RowNames in the question is confusing because RowNames is also a property of the table. From your description it doesn't seem like you are referring to the table's property, you are instead referring to the Strings you have stored in the first column info.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think both of you approaches work! Randum Guy, you are very right, I was using the table not in the way it is designed for, meaning the first column of my table were row titles as string which is not needed. The more efficient way was to use the row names with the key word 'RowNames' as an indicator of the row titles. Having fixed it `A=[A;newT]` or `array2table` (with keyword RowNames) works. However,  `A{end+1,:} = {'F9', zeros(1,14087)}`not as we are not dealing with cell data types. Anyway thank you very much guys